# How to create a live excel connection to Redshift

Tags: excel, amazon-redshift, dbvisualizer

I want to be able to connect excel with redshift.

So when I refresh this live connection in excel, it will refresh the query I write in redshift and return the newest result in excel.

I used to do it in a SQL Server using a stored procedure, and connect SQL Server with Excel using legacy wizard (under the get data option in data tab) - in the connection I specify the stored procedure, so every time I refresh Excel, it will fetch the updated result from SQL Server.

But now the company is using db visualizer to connect to redshift. I am not sure how to use the wizard to connect to Excel; do I need to use VBA? Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

dbvisualiser is just an IDE that can point to redshift. it has no bearing on what you are trying to achieve.

you need to set up a link from excel through ODBC to Redshift. for that you need you redshift

- host name
- port
- user name
- password

You would also need these things to connect through dbvisualiser

to get connected - you could follow the instructions here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-connection.html